# How to handle unit test with "large" test data of Nodejs AWS Lambda application

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jestjs, aws-serverless, aws-sam

When we are developing our Node applications (which then run Serverless in production and locally via SAM) we would like to use Jest to unittest our application. We are now faced with the issue that our testdata is 'large' (thousand rows of JSON and more) which SAM deploys to the Lambda aswell.

How is this supposed to be solved? Are we attacking the issue the wrong way?

Comment: What is the issue? The file is too large to upload? Process? More details are needed...

Comment: Well not too large to upload but it adds size which makes the inline code edit not work and also the lambda itself start slower (and deploy slower) (because more "code" is loaded). I was wondering if I either could exclude things via SAM deploy or if I am attacking the problem the wrong way.